# What is wrong with my notifyAll()?

Tags: java, multithreading

to create Fibonacci series

```
    public void run(){
        int a=0,b=1,c;
        while(a<=10000){
            prim chk= new prim(a);
            chk.start();
            synchronized (chk) {
                try {
                    sleep(200);
                    chk.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    return;
                }
            }
            c=a+b;
            a=b;
            b=c;
        }
     }
```

to check prime number I have created another thread (just for practice)

```
        public void run(){
            synchronized (this) {
                int fl=1;
                if(a==1||a==2)
                    fl=0;
                else
                    for(int i=2;i<=Math.sqrt(a);i++)
                        if(a%i==0)
                            fl=0;
                if(fl==0)
                    System.out.println(a);
            }
            notifyAll();
        }
```

there are many `IllegalMonitorState` exceptions in the output.

Comment: you cannot call `notifyAll();` from outside of synchronized block

Comment: To notify other threads observing (waiting) on some monitor your thread fist need to possess it. So you need to call `this.notifyAll` inside `synchronize(this)` block.

Comment: This has been asked many times before, for example, please see this [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13335367/why-does-this-code-result-in-illegalmonitorstate-exception) which was used to close your question. And for more similar questions/answers, please check out this [search of this site](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+IllegalMonitorStateException+notifyall). In fact, this second link is the most important since it will introduce you to the search capabilities of this site and help reduce unnecessary duplicate questions.

Comment: well I'm new. So I didn't knew.is there any way to close this question??

Comment: Don't worry about it, but in the future, do check out Google and this site's search capabilities first, as it is often likely that a question that you (or I) have will not be a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object#wait`, `Object#notifyAll` should be called from the `synchronized` block.